# Passing a parameter to a function with std::move, is there a difference if that parameter is declared as pass-by-value or with a move operand &&?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I'm curious if there's any difference (to the compiler) between these two. The only difference between them is that ValueClass takes the parameter in the constructor *by reference*

```
#include <string>

class ValueClass
{
public:
    ValueClass(std::string obj) : m_obj(std::move(obj)) {}

private:
    std::string m_obj;
};

class MoveClass
{
public:
    MoveClass(std::string&& obj) : m_obj(std::move(obj)) {}

private:
    std::string m_obj;
};

void SomeFunc()
{
    std::string a, b;

    a = "a";
    b = "b";

    ValueClass c(std::move(a));
    MoveClass d(std::move(b));
}
```

I had a quick check on [goldbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MqrRKk), and it does indeed look like the MoveClass constructor call results in fewer lines of assembly (assuming godbolt is accurate and didn't mis-attribute any lines of assembly).

So my question then becomes, why is there a difference? Is the compiler setting up some temporary storage where the string is moved into, and then immediately out of?

Is this something that should, in theory, be optimised away? In which case, are the differences purely for the programmer to imbue a function signature with more meaning and information, so that it's easier to understand for anyone who might want to call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ValueClass` requires the move constructor of `std::string` to be called twice: Once to create the `obj` parameter and then to initialize the `m_obj` member.

`MoveClass` requires only one move constructor of `std::string` to be called: `obj` is an (rvalue) reference to `b` (no new `std::string` object is constructed here). Only the `m_obj` initialization involves the `std::string` move constructor.

---

There is still the question whether it would be allowed to elide any of these calls (as an exception to the as-if rule). That is not the case though; neither member initialization nor function parameter initialization are a valid context for eliding constructors (or temporaries): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

---

Now, in the given code, there are not necessarily side effects that require the compiler to keep any of the constructor calls. In fact, if you don't perform the reassignment in `main`, `gcc` notices that the entire program has no side effect and can be optimized to a no-op.

https://godbolt.org/z/hxrVfC

You also didn't give `MSVC` the correct parameters. Highest optimization is `/O2`, not `-O3` (although `-O2` does work). Mind the compiler warnings!

Comment: Ah the -O3 was supplied by godbolt by default, so I guess there's a bug in their default parameters for MSVC